# Software to monitor home audio

Tags: audio, monitoring, audio-recording

During recent weeks, we had various arguments over noise disturbances with our neighbours. The details do not matter, but it would make things easier if I could record both our and their noises, to have a quantitative comparison.

I would like to have a software that uses the device microphone to record the audio surrounding a laptop (or desktop, PC, Mac, tablet, whatever). As long as the software is running, it records and saves a (low-quality) audio recording of everything that happens around the device.

To cope with the rather long recordings, the software would display the recordings in some block form, e.g. one hour per block. Each block shows the maximum and the average loudness (or similar metrics) during that time span. If you click on one of the blocks, you see that hour in smaller blocks, e.g. 5 minutes per block. Or, better, the software would show a waveform rendering of the hour, so you can immediately see when there were noises. And of course you can listen to the recorded audio of a block.

This way, I could immediately see at which time there were some noises, and how loud they were.

Is there a software that can be used for this use case, or something similar?

(of course this still needs distinguishing whether the noises were from our neighbours or ours, but let me deal with that)

Comment: a decibel reader and a camera should work. You can record the decibel reader, then compile data from timestamp and recorded decibel level.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to software use something like [Sound Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamebasic.decibel&gl=US) which is an app for measuring decibels. I'm not 100% sure this has the break up of data like you want but it has avg, min, and max